# Need some help, fixing up this function in R

Tags: r, string, list, function, dataframe

So I have this data frame `movies_names`, where the first column in the data frame consists of all the names, and the second column consists of all the movies they appeared in.

I want to create a function where if I enter their name , I get the all the movies they are in.

This is what I got

```
movies_names<- data.frame(name,movies) #this dataframe contains the names in the first column, and their corresponding movies in column 2


films <- function(x)
{

  print(movies_names[x,1])
}
```

The way I have it here is when I enter the number corresponding to their place in the list, it gives me the movie, but I'm stuck on how to change it so I can enter strings into my function rather than just numbers

Comment: Look up `%in%` (it's in `?match`).

Comment: You need to use `%in%` comparing `x` with something in the `movies_names` frame. Perhaps `movies_names[ movies_names[,1] %in% x, 2]` will return the second column for all rows where the first column is present in `x`. It's not the most robust (it still relies on a frame that is defined outside of the function), but it's a start for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out